ADO CI/CD for ADF - triggers not getting started in target environment
I have built a CI/CD release pipeline in DevOps to deploy from my Dev ADF to (currently) a UAT ADF. The pipeline works fine in terms of moving everything across, however the powershell script that is supposed to stop/start triggers is not working. By default, all my triggers in Dev are stopped, but I need them to be turned on in UAT. I have tried fiddling with the ps script, but I don't really know powershell. Can someone please review my script and tell me where the issue is?
param
(
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [String] $armTemplate,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [String] $ResourceGroupName,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [String] $DataFactoryName,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [Bool] $predeployment=$true,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)] [Bool] $deleteDeployment=$false
)

function getPipelineDependencies {
    param([System.Object] $activity)
    if ($activity.Pipeline) {
        return @($activity.Pipeline.ReferenceName)
    } elseif ($activity.Activities) {
        $result = @()
        $activity.Activities | ForEach-Object{ $result += getPipelineDependencies -activity $_ }
        return $result
    } elseif ($activity.ifFalseActivities -or $activity.ifTrueActivities) {
        $result = @()
        $activity.ifFalseActivities | Where-Object {$_ -ne $null} | ForEach-Object{ $result += getPipelineDependencies -activity $_ }
        $activity.ifTrueActivities | Where-Object {$_ -ne $null} | ForEach-Object{ $result += getPipelineDependencies -activity $_ }
        return $result
    } elseif ($activity.defaultActivities) {
        $result = @()
        $activity.defaultActivities | ForEach-Object{ $result += getPipelineDependencies -activity $_ }
        if ($activity.cases) {
            $activity.cases | ForEach-Object{ $_.activities } | ForEach-Object{$result += getPipelineDependencies -activity $_ }
        }
        return $result
    } else {
        return @()
    }
}

function pipelineSortUtil {
    param([Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactoryV2.Models.PSPipeline]$pipeline,
    [Hashtable] $pipelineNameResourceDict,
    [Hashtable] $visited,
    [System.Collections.Stack] $sortedList)
    if ($visited[$pipeline.Name] -eq $true) {
        return;
    }
    $visited[$pipeline.Name] = $true;
    $pipeline.Activities | ForEach-Object{ getPipelineDependencies -activity $_ -pipelineNameResourceDict $pipelineNameResourceDict}  | ForEach-Object{
        pipelineSortUtil -pipeline $pipelineNameResourceDict[$_] -pipelineNameResourceDict $pipelineNameResourceDict -visited $visited -sortedList $sortedList
    }
    $sortedList.Push($pipeline)

}

function Get-SortedPipelines {
    param(
        [string] $DataFactoryName,
        [string] $ResourceGroupName
    )
    $pipelines = Get-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
    $ppDict = @{}
    $visited = @{}
    $stack = new-object System.Collections.Stack
    $pipelines | ForEach-Object{ $ppDict[$_.Name] = $_ }
    $pipelines | ForEach-Object{ pipelineSortUtil -pipeline $_ -pipelineNameResourceDict $ppDict -visited $visited -sortedList $stack }
    $sortedList = new-object Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactoryV2.Models.PSPipeline]
    
    while ($stack.Count -gt 0) {
        $sortedList.Add($stack.Pop())
    }
    $sortedList
}

function triggerSortUtil {
    param([Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactoryV2.Models.PSTrigger]$trigger,
    [Hashtable] $triggerNameResourceDict,
    [Hashtable] $visited,
    [System.Collections.Stack] $sortedList)
    if ($visited[$trigger.Name] -eq $true) {
        return;
    }
    $visited[$trigger.Name] = $true;
    if ($trigger.Properties.DependsOn) {
        $trigger.Properties.DependsOn | Where-Object {$_ -and $_.ReferenceTrigger} | ForEach-Object{
            triggerSortUtil -trigger $triggerNameResourceDict[$_.ReferenceTrigger.ReferenceName] -triggerNameResourceDict $triggerNameResourceDict -visited $visited -sortedList $sortedList
        }
    }
    $sortedList.Push($trigger)
}

function Get-SortedTriggers {
    param(
        [string] $DataFactoryName,
        [string] $ResourceGroupName
    )
    $triggers = Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName
    $triggerDict = @{}
    $visited = @{}
    $stack = new-object System.Collections.Stack
    $triggers | ForEach-Object{ $triggerDict[$_.Name] = $_ }
    $triggers | ForEach-Object{ triggerSortUtil -trigger $_ -triggerNameResourceDict $triggerDict -visited $visited -sortedList $stack }
    $sortedList = new-object Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactoryV2.Models.PSTrigger]
    
    while ($stack.Count -gt 0) {
        $sortedList.Add($stack.Pop())
    }
    $sortedList
}

function Get-SortedLinkedServices {
    param(
        [string] $DataFactoryName,
        [string] $ResourceGroupName
    )
    $linkedServices = Get-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName
    $LinkedServiceHasDependencies = @('HDInsightLinkedService', 'HDInsightOnDemandLinkedService', 'AzureBatchLinkedService')
    $Akv = 'AzureKeyVaultLinkedService'
    $HighOrderList = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactoryV2.Models.PSLinkedService]
    $RegularList = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactoryV2.Models.PSLinkedService]
    $AkvList = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactoryV2.Models.PSLinkedService]

    $linkedServices | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.Properties.GetType().Name -in $LinkedServiceHasDependencies) {
            $HighOrderList.Add($_)
        }
        elseif ($_.Properties.GetType().Name -eq $Akv) {
            $AkvList.Add($_)
        }
        else {
            $RegularList.Add($_)
        }
    }

    $SortedList = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactoryV2.Models.PSLinkedService]($HighOrderList.Count + $RegularList.Count + $AkvList.Count)
    $SortedList.AddRange($HighOrderList)
    $SortedList.AddRange($RegularList)
    $SortedList.AddRange($AkvList)
    $SortedList
}

$templateJson = Get-Content $armTemplate | ConvertFrom-Json
$resources = $templateJson.resources

#Triggers 
Write-Host "Getting triggers"
$triggersInTemplate = $resources | Where-Object { $_.type -eq "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/triggers" }
$triggerNamesInTemplate = $triggersInTemplate | ForEach-Object {$_.name.Substring(37, $_.name.Length-40)}

$triggersDeployed = Get-SortedTriggers -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName

$triggersToStop = $triggersDeployed | Where-Object { $triggerNamesInTemplate -contains $_.Name } | ForEach-Object { 
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Name = $_.Name
        TriggerType = $_.Properties.GetType().Name 
    }
}
$triggersToDelete = $triggersDeployed | Where-Object { $triggerNamesInTemplate -notcontains $_.Name } | ForEach-Object { 
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Name = $_.Name
        TriggerType = $_.Properties.GetType().Name 
    }
}
$triggersToStart = $triggersInTemplate | Where-Object { $_.properties.runtimeState -eq "Started" -and ($_.properties.pipelines.Count -gt 0 -or $_.properties.pipeline.pipelineReference -ne $null)} | ForEach-Object { 
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Name = $_.name.Substring(37, $_.name.Length-40)
        TriggerType = $_.Properties.type
    }
}

if ($predeployment -eq $true) {
    #Stop all triggers
    Write-Host "Stopping deployed triggersn"
    $triggersToStop | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.TriggerType -eq "BlobEventsTrigger" -or $_.TriggerType -eq "CustomEventsTrigger") {
            Write-Host "Unsubscribing" $_.Name "from events"
            $status = Remove-AzDataFactoryV2TriggerSubscription -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name $_.Name
            while ($status.Status -ne "Disabled"){
                Start-Sleep -s 15
                $status = Get-AzDataFactoryV2TriggerSubscriptionStatus -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name $_.Name
            }
        }
        Write-Host "Stopping trigger" $_.Name
        Stop-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name $_.Name -Force
    }
}
else {
    #Deleted resources
    #pipelines
    Write-Host "Getting pipelines"
Write-Host $pipelinesADF = Get-SortedPipelines -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
Write-Host "Pipelines from ADF:" ($pipelinesADF | Out-String)
Write-Host $pipelinesTemplate = $resources | Where-Object { $_.type -eq "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines" }
Write-Host $pipelinesNames = $pipelinesTemplate | ForEach-Object {$_.name.Substring(37, $_.name.Length-40)}
Write-Host "Pipelines from template:" ($pipelinesNames | Out-String)
Write-Host $deletedpipelines = $pipelinesADF | Where-Object { $pipelinesNames -notcontains $_.Name }
Write-Host "Deleted pipelines:" ($deletedpipelines | Out-String)

# Dataflows
Write-Host "Getting dataflows"
$dataflowsADF = Get-AzDataFactoryV2DataFlow -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
Write-Host "Dataflows from ADF:" ($dataflowsADF | Out-String)
$dataflowsTemplate = $resources | Where-Object { $_.type -eq "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/dataflows" }
$dataflowsNames = $dataflowsTemplate | ForEach-Object {$_.name.Substring(37, $_.name.Length-40)}
Write-Host "Dataflows from template:" ($dataflowsNames | Out-String)
$deleteddataflow = $dataflowsADF | Where-Object { $dataflowsNames -notcontains $_.Name }
Write-Host "Deleted dataflows:" ($deleteddataflow | Out-String)

# Datasets
Write-Host "Getting datasets"
$datasetsADF = Get-AzDataFactoryV2Dataset -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
Write-Host "Datasets from ADF:" ($datasetsADF | Out-String)
$datasetsTemplate = $resources | Where-Object { $_.type -eq "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets" }
$datasetsNames = $datasetsTemplate | ForEach-Object {$_.name.Substring(37, $_.name.Length-40)}
Write-Host "Datasets from template:" ($datasetsNames | Out-String)
$deleteddataset = $datasetsADF | Where-Object { $datasetsNames -notcontains $_.Name }
Write-Host "Deleted datasets:" ($deleteddataset | Out-String)

# Linked Services
Write-Host "Getting linked services"
$linkedservicesADF = Get-SortedLinkedServices -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
Write-Host "Linked services from ADF:" ($linkedservicesADF | Out-String)
$linkedservicesTemplate = $resources | Where-Object { $_.type -eq "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices" }
$linkedservicesNames = $linkedservicesTemplate | ForEach-Object {$_.name.Substring(37, $_.name.Length-40)}
Write-Host "Linked services from template:" ($linkedservicesNames | Out-String)
$deletedlinkedservices = $linkedservicesADF | Where-Object { $linkedservicesNames -notcontains $_.Name }
Write-Host "Deleted linked services:" ($deletedlinkedservices | Out-String)

# Integration Runtimes
Write-Host "Getting integration runtimes"
$integrationruntimesADF = Get-AzDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
Write-Host "Integration runtimes from ADF:" ($integrationruntimesADF | Out-String)
$integrationruntimesTemplate = $resources | Where-Object { $_.type -eq "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/integrationruntimes" }
$integrationruntimesNames = $integrationruntimesTemplate | ForEach-Object {$_.name.Substring(37, $_.name.Length-40)}
Write-Host "Integration runtimes from template:" ($integrationruntimesNames | Out-String)
$deletedintegrationruntimes = $integrationruntimesADF | Where-Object { $integrationruntimesNames -notcontains $_.Name }
Write-Host "Deleted integration runtimes:" ($deletedintegrationruntimes | Out-String)

    #Delete resources
    Write-Host "Deleting triggers"
    $triggersToDelete | ForEach-Object { 
        Write-Host "Deleting trigger "  $_.Name
        $trig = Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -name $_.Name -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName
        if ($trig.RuntimeState -eq "Started") {
            if ($_.TriggerType -eq "BlobEventsTrigger" -or $_.TriggerType -eq "CustomEventsTrigger") {
                Write-Host "Unsubscribing trigger" $_.Name "from events"
                $status = Remove-AzDataFactoryV2TriggerSubscription -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name $_.Name
                while ($status.Status -ne "Disabled"){
                    Start-Sleep -s 15
                    $status = Get-AzDataFactoryV2TriggerSubscriptionStatus -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name $_.Name
                }
            }
            Stop-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name $_.Name -Force 
        }
        Remove-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -Name $_.Name -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Force 
    }
    Write-Host "Deleting pipelines"

if ($null -ne $deletedpipelines) {
    $deletedpipelines | ForEach-Object { 
        Write-Host "Deleting pipeline " $_.Name
        Remove-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -Name $_.Name -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Force 
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "No pipelines to delete"
}
    Write-Host "Deleting dataflows"
    $deleteddataflow | ForEach-Object { 
        Write-Host "Deleting dataflow " $_.Name
        Remove-AzDataFactoryV2DataFlow -Name $_.Name -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Force 
    }
    Write-Host "Deleting datasets"
    $deleteddataset | ForEach-Object { 
        Write-Host "Deleting dataset " $_.Name
        Remove-AzDataFactoryV2Dataset -Name $_.Name -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Force 
    }
    Write-Host "Deleting linked services"
    $deletedlinkedservices | ForEach-Object { 
        Write-Host "Deleting Linked Service " $_.Name
        Remove-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService -Name $_.Name -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Force 
    }
    Write-Host "Deleting integration runtimes"
    $deletedintegrationruntimes | ForEach-Object { 
        Write-Host "Deleting integration runtime " $_.Name
        Remove-AzDataFactoryV2IntegrationRuntime -Name $_.Name -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Force 
    }

    if ($deleteDeployment -eq $true) {
        Write-Host "Deleting ARM deployment ... under resource group: " $ResourceGroupName
        $deployments = Get-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
        $deploymentsToConsider = $deployments | Where { $_.DeploymentName -like "ArmTemplate_master*" -or $_.DeploymentName -like "ArmTemplateForFactory*" } | Sort-Object -Property Timestamp -Descending
        $deploymentName = $deploymentsToConsider[0].DeploymentName

       Write-Host "Deployment to be deleted: " $deploymentName
        $deploymentOperations = Get-AzResourceGroupDeploymentOperation -DeploymentName $deploymentName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
        $deploymentsToDelete = $deploymentOperations | Where { $_.properties.targetResource.id -like "*Microsoft.Resources/deployments*" }

        $deploymentsToDelete | ForEach-Object { 
            Write-host "Deleting inner deployment: " $_.properties.targetResource.id
            Remove-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Id $_.properties.targetResource.id
        }
        Write-Host "Deleting deployment: " $deploymentName
        Remove-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $deploymentName
    }

# Start active triggers in UAT
Write-Host "Starting active triggers in UAT"
Write-Host $triggersToStart | ForEach-Object { 
Write-Host    $triggerName = $_.name.Substring(37, $_.name.Length-40) # Extracting the trigger name from the ARM template name
Write-Host "Checking trigger status for:" $triggerName

    $existingTrigger = Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name $triggerName
    
    if ($existingTrigger.RuntimeState -ne "Stopped") {
        if ($_.TriggerType -eq "BlobEventsTrigger" -or $_.TriggerType -eq "CustomEventsTrigger") {
            Write-Host "Subscribing" $triggerName "to events"
            $status = Add-AzDataFactoryV2TriggerSubscription -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name $triggerName
            while ($status.Status -ne "Stopped") {
                Start-Sleep -s 15
                $status = Get-AzDataFactoryV2TriggerSubscriptionStatus -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name $triggerName
            }
        }
        Write-Host "Starting trigger" $triggerName
        Start-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name $triggerName -Force
    } else {
        Write-Host "Trigger" $triggerName "is already started."
    }
}
}

Need to mention that this is a script that Microsoft provide.
I have tried modifying the RuntimeState mentioned at the bottom of the script to look for Stopped triggers, I have tried adding Write-Host before all lines so I can see what it's doing.
# Start active triggers in UAT
Write-Host "Starting active triggers in UAT"
Write-Host $triggersToStart | ForEach-Object { 
Write-Host    $triggerName = $_.name.Substring(37, $_.name.Length-40) # Extracting the trigger name from the ARM template name
Write-Host "Checking trigger status for:" $triggerName

    $existingTrigger = Get-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name $triggerName
    
    if ($existingTrigger.RuntimeState -ne "Stopped") {
        if ($_.TriggerType -eq "BlobEventsTrigger" -or $_.TriggerType -eq "CustomEventsTrigger") {
            Write-Host "Subscribing" $triggerName "to events"
            $status = Add-AzDataFactoryV2TriggerSubscription -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name $triggerName
            while ($status.Status -ne "Stopped") {
                Start-Sleep -s 15
                $status = Get-AzDataFactoryV2TriggerSubscriptionStatus -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name $triggerName
            }
        }
        Write-Host "Starting trigger" $triggerName
        Start-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $DataFactoryName -Name $triggerName -Force
    } else {
        Write-Host "Trigger" $triggerName "is already started."
    }
}
}

